# How to override list-ios style on an IonList

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have an ion list that is contained in an ion content like so:

```
<IonContent class="sub-list-container" scrollY={true} style={{ "background": "red" }}>
    <IonList class="sub-list">
        <IonMenuToggle autoHide={false} key={p.title}>
            {
                p.children.map(el => el)
            }
        </IonMenuToggle>
    </IonList>
</IonContent>
```

The styles for this are:

```css
.sub-list-container {
    --background: var(--primary-dark);
}
```

Inside the list is of course some ion items. I have customised their separator line to be a gradient of white to transparent like this:

```
border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) 1 1;
```

This is so the line will blend into any background colour that I put it on. This works fine for a list on a different page however on the list I showed above, it goes from white to black. The issue isn't the gradient but the colour of the background behind it. I've tried setting every list, every ion content in the menu to the colour I need the background to be but it still looks like this:
[image]
As you can see, even though background is grey (and even the ion content's background is grey too), the line still blends to black.
After doing some digging in chrome, I found that this:

```
.list-ios {
    background: var(--ion-item-background, var(--ion-background-color, #fff));
}
```

is causing that. If I disable that style then I can see whatever background colour I set instead of the black like so:
[image]

Unfortunately I have not found a way to disable this style. The `mode` of the ion list can only be `ios` or `md` so it will always have to have one of these styles. Even setting the background colours to `!important` does not work.
Is there anyway I can override this `list-ios` style?

Comment: can you try adding this style to the css/scss file? `.sub-list-container .list-ios {  background: inherit; }`

Comment: That has fixed it - thank you!